# Does the contrast matrix I have made address the question I am trying to answer?

Tags: rna-seq, edger, limma

I have the following design matrix:

```
mm_noreps.interactions <- model.matrix(~condition*TRAPed)
```

Both variables are factors condition has 4 levels and TRAPed has 2 levels.

```
pheatmap(mm_noreps.interactions)
```

[image]

I want to use the following contrasts:

1. TRAP positive (just consider this a drug treatment) vs TRAP negative in all conditions,
   c(-1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0)
2. FearRecallpositive vs all other condition's positive cells c(0,0,-1/3,0,-1/3,-1/3,0,1), and
3. FearRecallpostive vs all other conditions c(-1/7,-1/7,-1/7,-1/7,-1/7,-1/7,-1/7,1).

The main question I have is are there differentially expressed genes specific to the FearRecall:TRAPedpostive interaction.  Does contrast 3 address this? The other two are more sanity checks than actual contrasts of interest.